# Directory.GetFiles() but only include files with a specific content (for e.g. "my file contents") using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I want to search all XML files which contains a special tag, e.g. 'field' within their contents. How can I achieve this with `Directory.GetFiles(...)` method in C# ?

```
string[] filePathsFields = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Code\", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let we have

```
string path= "E:\\Code";
```

then

```
IEnumerable<XDocument> q =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml") // iterate thru each XML file into the dir
    .Select(x => XDocument.Load(x)) // load each file into memory
    .Where(d => doc.Descendants("field").Count() > 0); // determine tag existence
```

or

```
IEnumerable<XDocument> q = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml")
                           let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                           where doc.Descendants("field").Count() > 0
                           select doc;
```

---

Pre .NET 4.0 solution:

Just replace

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.xml")
```

with

```
Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

---

Select the resulting node itself:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>> qq = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                                        let field = doc.Descendants("field")
                                        let ignore = doc.Descendants("ignore")
                                        where field.Count() > 0 && ignore.Count() == 0
                                        select field;
```

returns nested `IEnumerable<>` because each document can contain several resulting nodes.

---

To select only file names:

```
IEnumerable<string> q = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                        where doc.Descendants("field").Count() > 0
                        select file;
```

or if you don't want to load data to appropriate XDocument object:

```
IEnumerable<string> q = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        let data = File.ReadAllText(file)
                        where data.Contains("field")
                        select file;
```

but the last will return a lot of additional stuff and junk, I guess.

---

File and folder exclusion:

```
var q = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        where !new[] { "file1", "file2" }.Contains(file)
        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
        where doc.Descendants("field").Count() > 0
        select file;

var q = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        where !new[] { "c:\\foo\\bar", "c:\\blah\\blah" }.Contains(Path.GetDirectoryName(file))
        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
        where doc.Descendants("field").Count() > 0
        select file;
```

Attributes count condition:

```
var q = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
        from f  in doc.Descendants("field")
        where f.Attributes("id").Count() > 0 && f.Attributes("name").Count() > 0
        select file;
```

Comment: +1 for working code but for very large XML files it might be more efficient to use File.LoadAllText() and String.Contains(), skipping the XML parsing.

Comment: What options do we have if I dont want to use EnumerateFiles because I'm still sticking to .NET 3.5 and EnumerateFiles method doesn't exist in 3.5. Its even ridiculous to see Microsoft is also on mistake here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(VS.90).aspx That's why I am getting this error 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateFiles'

Comment: @Anns: I don't know what does the mean mentioning that method on .NET 3.5 page remarking `.NET Framework: Supported in: 4`

Comment: @abatishchev this is also what I was thinking :)...Microsoft rocks, even in their own way :D

Comment: @abatishchev how can we ignore some tag (children) within the 'field' tag?

Comment: @Anna: `doc.Descendants("field").Count() > 0 && doc.Descendants("ignore").Count() == 0` I guess

Comment: @ abatishchev täck from Sweden ;)

Comment: @Anna: Glad it helped! Привет from Russia! :)

Comment: @abatishchev I'm having an issue. Files are not retreived correctly and also how to query IEnumerable<XDocument> q , to get the file path or XML string? Sorry, I'm don't know much about Linq ;(

Comment: @Anna: Delete please a duplicate ;)

Comment: @abatishchev ah, sorry for duplicate ;)

Comment: @abatishchev thanks for the update but it boils down to the fact that I'm unable to fetch the file using your query. My question again is that I want to fetch all xml files within the directory which contains the tag for e.g. <Field Name="LinkTitle" ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" DisplayName="Content type name" Sealed="TRUE"      SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitle" Type="Text" Required="TRUE"> </Field>. Your queries for Linq are not working. Is there a way to fetch only the filepaths of such files then I can do the parsing at my own. thanks

Comment: @Anna: See my update post. And btw, you can use tilde to highlight code into comments: `<Field Name="LinkTitle".. />`

Comment: Wow!!! you are the man!!!! I made +1 to every post/comment you made on this page :D

Comment: bravo, I'm impressed by your Linq skills ;)

Comment: I bet this would be my one last query :D...what if I want to exclude files which are starting some specific name say "Manifest.xml" and the files which has element 'Field', but this element field is only having one attribute i.e. Name. In other words, for the second query I only need Field elements in the xml files which have more than one attribute like Name, ID, DisplayName etc etc.

Comment: or please tell me how Can I exclude a specific folder from this whole search :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you will have to get all XML files first, and then open them one after another and check the contents for your `<tag>`. There is no magic shortcut here.

Btw, using `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` (Fx4) is much more efficient, certainly for a large number of files. It probably won't help to parallelize this.

Comment: What options do we have in .NET 3.5 to do this in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If you want to filter by content, you need to open and read each file to see if it contains your content.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this Linq statement ?

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\\Code", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.Contains("<Field "));
```

Comment: Could be made to work but `s` is a a string, you'd have to write `.Contains()` as an extension method that opens it as a file. You'd want to keep that a very local extension.

Comment: And String already has a Contains() method so you'd better use another name.

Comment: I think there is no even sense to create an extension method, just some static, e.g. `SearchTag(string filePath, string tagName)`

Comment: I agree with abatishchev here!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the target OS you can use [Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628790%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to do the job. One limitation (IMHO) is that it looks like Windows Search only works if the folders you are interested in are indexed.

A sample that I run on my machine:

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace TestQindowsSearch
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Top 10 System.ItemUrl FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:h:/projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net' AND CONTAINS('IActivatable') AND CONTAINS(System.ItemUrl, '.cs')", conn);

            var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (result.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produced:

```
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o.CS.Optional/bin/Release/Db4objects.Db4o.xml
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o/Db4objects.Db4o/TA/IActivatable.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o/Db4objects.Db4o/Internal/Activation/TPUnspecifiedUpdateDepth.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o/Db4objects.Db4o/Internal/Activation/TPFixedUpdateDepth.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o/Db4objects.Db4o/Internal/Activation/ActivatableBase.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4oTutorial/Db4odoc.Tutorial.Chapters/F1/Chapter9/Car.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4oTutorial/Db4odoc.Tutorial.Chapters/F1/Chapter9/SensorReadout.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4oTutorial/Db4odoc.Tutorial.Chapters/F1/Chapter8/Car.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4oTutorial/Db4odoc.Tutorial.Chapters/F1/Chapter8/Pilot.cs
file:H:/Projects/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4oTutorial/Db4odoc.Tutorial.Chapters/F1/Chapter8/SensorReadout.cs
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Hope this helps

Adriano